# Saving custom application notifications, error strings

Tags: c++, winapi

what is the best way to save notify, error, warning string for GUI application? Currently I just create const char* strings everytime the application needs to process and popup a notification string. how should i handle messages without regenerating memory for temporary strings?

Comment: Does the app currently have a problem with using a lot of memory for these strings?  Or, is this just a guestimation that there is going to be a problem?

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your question if you are creating these strings *dynamically*. If not, storing them in a resource file is the best solution for more reasons than memory management. Otherwise, ignore the temptation to optimize something you haven't profiled as being a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You tagged win32api I think You are using windows :D...

So one solution would be to save your strings as [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646979.aspx).

They are easy to maintain and can be changed/updated easily...

Hope this helps:)...